# Slow performance when trying to combine multiple solr cores using SolrEntityProcessor

Tags: solr, solrj, solr4

i am creating a solr core by combining 3 different solr cores and its taking like 23 docs/sec which is very slow. I think the problem is the parent entity (Solr A) has 70K records and its trying to repeat 70K times for each of its sub entities. Is there a way to fetch 70K records just once and then loop through the sub entities. Solr B and Solr C also has approx 70K records each. I am using Solr5

below is my config for new solr core

```
<entity name="a" processor="SolrEntityProcessor" url="http://solrCoreA" query="*:*"
    fl="*">

<field column="a1" name="a1" />
<field column="a2" name="a2" />

<entity name="b" processor="SolrEntityProcessor" url="http://solrCoreB" query="${a.a1}:b1"
    fl="b1,b2">
<field column="b1" name="b1" />
<field column="b2" name="b2" />

<entity name="c" processor="SolrEntityProcessor" url="http://solrCoreC" query="${b.b2}:c2"
    fl="c1,c2">
<field column="c1" name="c1" />
<field column="c2" name="c2" />
</entity>
</entity>
</entity>
```

Comment: Your assumption is correct. If you're spending time looking up the same entries in the dependent collections each time, you can use the cache support to speed it up to avoid that; but otherwise, writing your own indexing script will let you optimize the import in any way you want - and is usually not that many lines of code either.

Comment: thanks for your response.. sorry I am new to solr caching. the solrConfig.xml seem to have caching enabled for query cache.. but I don't see any improvements, do you have any refernces I can check

Comment: The data import handler lookup cache is different from what is configured in `solrconfig.xml` - see `cacheImpl` here: https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_6/uploading-structured-data-store-data-with-the-data-import-handler.html#entity-caching - however, this will only speed up repeated lookups for the same value - it does not support building a one time map and looking up values in that.